# Numpy sub-array assignment with advanced, mixed indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

### Original question

I am getting a very odd error message when I try to assign some of the elements of an array.  I am using a combination of a slice and a set of indices.  See the following simple example.

```
 import scipy as sp

 a = sp.zeros((3, 4, 5))
 b = sp.ones((4, 5))

 I = sp.array([0, 1, 3])

 b[:, I] = a[0, :, I]
```

This code raises the following `ValueError`:

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,4) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,4)

--

#### Follow up

Be careful when using a combination of a slice and seq. of integers.  As pointed out on github:

```
x = rand(3, 5, 7)

print(x[0, :, [0,1]].shape)
# (2, 5)

print(x[0][:, [0,1]].shape)
# (5, 2)
```

This is how numpy is designed to work, but it is nevertheless a bit confusing that x[0][:, I] is not the same as x[0, :, I].  Since this is the behavior I want I choose to use x[0][:, I] in my code.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: would `[0,1 4]` actually be `[0,1,4]` (with a comma between 1 and 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are some errors in copying your code to question.

But I suspect there's a known problem with indexing:

```
In [73]: a=np.zeros((2,3,4)); b=np.ones((3,4)); I=np.array([0,1])
```

Make `I` 2 elements.  Indexing `b` gives the expected (3,2) shape.  3 rows from the slice, 2 columns from `I` indexing

```
In [74]: b[:,I].shape
Out[74]: (3, 2)
```

But with 3d `a` we get the transpose.

```
In [75]: a[0,:,I].shape
Out[75]: (2, 3)
```

and assignment would produce an error

```
In [76]: b[:,I]=a[0,:,I]
...
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

It's putting the 2 element dimension defined by `I` first, and the 3 element from `:` second.  It's a case of mixed advanced indexing that has been discussed earlier - and there's a bug issue as well.  (I'll have to look those up).

You are probably using a newer `numpy` (or `scipy`) and getting a different error message.

It's documented that indexing with two arrays or lists, and slice in the middle, puts the slice at the end, e.g.

```
In [86]: a[[[0],[0],[1],[1]],:,[0,1]].shape
Out[86]: (4, 2, 3)
```

The same thing is happening with `a[0,:,[0,1]]`.  But there's a good argument that it shouldn't be this way.

As to a fix, you could transpose a value, or change the indexing

```
In [88]: b[:,I]=a[0:1,:,I]

In [90]: b[:,I]=a[0,:,I].T

In [91]: b
Out[91]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])

In [92]: b[:,I]=a[0][:,I]
```

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7030

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6256

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful to know . . . slices in the middle of index lists get pushed to the last dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Here I get this error with indices `[0,1,4]`:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 4
```

Its suggesting the value `4` is being used as an index, while the SIZE 4 implies the max index would be 3.

EDIT: now that you changed it to `[0, 1, 3]`, it's running fine here.

EDIT: with your current code, I get the same error, but when I print the arrays themselves, they have a transverse shape:

```
print b[:, I]
print a[0, :, I]

[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it looks like you're missing a comma on the line 6:

```
I = sp.array([0,1,4])
```

Secondly, I would expect the value 4 in the array I to raise an IndexError, since both a and b have a max dimension of 4. I suspect you might want:

```
I = sp.array([0,1,3])
```

Making these changes run the program for me, and I got b as:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Which I suspect is what you want.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that this test case does actually run so I changed the example.  For some reason  the smaller array sizes didn't raise the error I am experiencing.